# rbac for asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, rbac

Is there an open rbac framework for asp.net? there a few solutions for rails but i cant find a simple rbac system for asp.net. is there something that can be used and extended?

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.developerdotstar.com/community/node/482) looks like a good place to start (it is best to drill into the links the author references for more information, but make sure that you read the article as well):

> **Implementing RBAC on .Net**:
>
> Recently I worked on RBAC (Role based
>   access control) implementation within
>   .Net. A comprehensive work on this
>   topic is done by Mark Strembeck XoRBAC
>   Home Details on RBAC concept can be
>   found at NIST RBAC
>
> While the design approach given in
>   Strembeck's work was comprehensive
>   enough to be realized on .Net, the
>   default implementation (done on XoTcl)
>   used extensive patterns from the
>   language (e.g. ability to use an
>   object as a class!), so a quick port
>   of that to a complete .Net
>   implementation of the design would
>   have taken a bit of an effort in my
>   current project. Well, instead of then
>   implementing the solution, I selected
>   MS Authorization Manager (I know folks
>   will say, Dah... that would have been
>   a no brainer). This is a small library
>   and a management console prrovided on
>   Windows 2003 and 2000 that implements
>   most of the RBAC requirements.

Comment: This uses AzMan (windows authentication), what if we want to do this using custom code and database?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've missed the point here, but ASP.NET ships with a pretty robust Role Provider framework - it should be very easy to find many open source implementations, if you really don't want to use the implementation that it comes with.

Comment: you're right. but as far as i know it's based on sites/url's. so you can say: role:foo can access site:bar. but what if i have different actions on a site? e.g. role user should be able to create new "contract" but only role "checker" should be able to edit certain fields and change the status.

Answer (score 0):

A comprehensive article on RBAC was found on [RBAC Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control).  Instead of researching on how to implement the features mentioned in the article, I tried to find security framework which allows a non-technical guy like me to apply security on asp.net applications and found following frameworks:

1. Portal Guard
2. Visual Guard
3. Member Protect